# Semantic UI Regex Parser with starting character

Tags: regex, semantic-ui

Field can't contain a starting `v` or `V`

```
{type:'regExp[/[^vV]/]', prompt: "don't start with v" }
{type:'regExp[/^vV/]', prompt: "don't start with v" }
{type:'regExp[/^(v|V)/]', prompt: "don't start with v" }
{type:'regExp[/^(v|V)[.]*/]', prompt: "don't start with v" }
```

none is working. no idea why.

even the easiest one doesn't work

```
{type:'regExp[/^y/]', prompt: "don't be y" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rubberduck ftw:

```
    {type:'regExp[/^[^vV]/]', prompt: "can't start with version" }
```